# Barchart for each row in dataframe

Tags: r, plot, bar-chart, diagram

I have a dataframe and I want a barplot for each row in this dataframe.

```
for(i in levels(myDf$name)) {
    barplot(cbind(unlist(myDf[i, 1:2]), unlist(myDf[i, 3:4])), beside=TRUE)
}
```

However, that does not work. It gives me no output... How would I plot that in one window so that I can export it to a file?!

*edit:

```
myDf<-data.frame(name=c('xyz','ybc','def'),
              var1=c(2,8,7), 
              var2=c(1,4,5),
              var3=c(3.8,2.5,8.4),
              var4=c(93.8,42.5,91.4))
```

Comment: Can you please give a glimpse of dataset by head() or dput()?

Comment: @KunalPuri added some data

Comment: Do any warning/error messages get printed to the console?

Comment: @LukeSingham no, nothing. The plot window simply stays empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(i in seq(myDf$name)) {
    barplot(cbind(unlist(myDf[i, 1:2]), unlist(myDf[i, 3:4])), beside=TRUE)
}
```

Comment: same as with my code. The plot window stays empty!+

Comment: Interesting, I get errors when using `levels`, using `seq` fixes the problem for me.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood it correctly, then here is an alternative.

```
data <- t(myDf[,2:5])

colnames(data) <- myDf$name

barplot(data,legend.text = rownames(data),beside=T,xlab='Row', ylab='Value')
```

[image: graph]